# Changing tick values of matlab .fig

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matlab figure given to me where the x axis values range from 0 to 4500 time steps. Each time step corresponds to 1.8e-8 seconds. I want to convert the ticks to seconds so I have 0,0.0900,0.1800,0.2700,0.3600,0.4500,0.5400,0.6300,0.7200,0.8100 seconds.

Is there a way to do this in the figure plotter? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the actual data, then once you have opened the .fig file you can change the labels simply by doing

```matlab
set(gca, 'XTickLabel' , {'0' '0.09' '0.18' '0.27' '0.36' '0.45' '0.54' '0.63' '0.72' '0.81'})
```

[image]

If instead you want to modify the data, then after opening the figure file you can first get the handle to the axis with `gca`, then next get the handle of the plot, and finally get the underlying data and modify it:

```matlab
ax1 = gca;                          % get the handle to the axis
plt1 = get(ax1,'Children');         % get the handle to the plot
xdata = get(plt1,'XData');          % retrieve x data from the plot
xdata_seconds = xdata * 1.8e-4;     % convert x data to desired units
set(plt1, 'XData', xdata_seconds)   % put the new data into the plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply look for the children plot in the axis and modify its XData:

```
x = 1:4500;
y = rand(size(x));
ax = axes;
plot(ax, x, y, '-r');
```

The plot now will have ticks from 1 to 4500.

```
ax.Children.XData = ax.Children.XData.*1.8e-8;
```

and now it is instead converted in seconds.

If the axes contain more than one children, you might want to find the correct one and use its index in the call ax.Children(idx).XData.